# ActionBar/Toolbar not showing on Lollipop version of app

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm currently trying to convert my app to lollipop material design and have run into some problems with the actionbar/toolbar. Implementing everything the way I did, the actionbar/toolbar won't show on either a lollipop or kitkat device. Perhaps someone could look at my themes, styles, activity_main (where I hold a bunch of fragments and is the only place I put the toolbar xml code), and mainactivity.

Thanks.

values/styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Set AppCompat’s actionBarStyle -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@menu/action_menu</item>

    <!-- The rest of your attributes -->
</style>

</resources>
```

values/themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_blue_grey_800</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_blue_grey_950</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerView"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_border"
        android:divider="@null" />
</RelativeLayout>
<!--
         <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.shamu11.madlibsportable.MadlibsSelect"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

-->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    OnItemClickListener {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Fragment fragment = new MadlibsSelect();

    fragment = new MadlibsSelect();

    FragmentTransaction fm = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
    fm.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fm.commit();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.action_menu);

    //ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    //bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#428bca")));

    ...more stuff happen down here including adding nav drawer.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change you're activity_main.xml as follows

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawerList"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_border"
            android:divider="@null" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!--
         <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.shamu11.madlibsportable.MadlibsSelect"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and If you're using setSupportActionBar then toolbar.inflateMenu won't work.

For more details check this post [Android Usages Of Toolbar](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2014/11/android-usages-issues-of-toolbar.html). It may help you.

Comment: Worst kind of answer. Are the rest of the people supposed to do a diff on those two files now?

Answer (score 4):

Your activity has to extend from [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) when using the new AppCompat library.

Comment: Already doing that, also implementing onitemclicklistener

I added that code for clarification.

Comment: @shamu11 Have you tried changing your parent theme to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" You're already declaring the toolbar in your layout so you should be fine.

Comment: Actually I just changed <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> from true to false and now I have an action bar! Can you recommend a way to go a tinker with this action bar and add the toggle to it? Thanks!

Comment: it seems on kitkat, it doesn't go back to an actionbar, it just displays a little header saying the name of my app. So it seems not to be the fully functioning way to go, but this is something.

Comment: Do you mean the Navigation Drawer toggle? The toolbar should behave exactly as the old ActionBar, Just add the toggle like you would normally do with an ActionBar.

Comment: okay, figure all that out. Do you have any theory for why the action bar isn't appearing in the pre-lollipop devices? I appreciate the help!

Comment: Try removing these elements: <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

Comment: this coupled with the answer above solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes this happen , I have wasted over an hour to fix this.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
```

This will automatically sync and finally show the toogle icon.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

That works for me, Hope that helps.